# How to reduce the number of methods omitted by Rubinius' profiler

Tags: ruby, profiling, rubinius

When I run Rubinius' [profiler](http://rubini.us/doc/en/tools/profiler/), using something like

```
ruby -Xprofiler.graph test/test_suite.rb
```

with the following within the test suite

```
# Code for actual tests here

# create a profiler instance
profiler = Rubinius::Profiler::Instrumenter.new

# start the profiler
profiler.start

# Run test unit now
require 'test/unit'
class Test::Unit::Runner
  @@stop_auto_run = true
end
Test::Unit::Runner.new.run(ARGV)

profiler.stop

# print out the profiler info
profiler.show  # takes on IO object, defaults to STDOUT
```

I often see something like

```
1,379 methods omitted

1,424 methods called a total of 0 times
```

presumably because the remaining methods are too small to meet some threshold of time taken.

I tried using something like `-Xprofiler.threshold=10000`, but it didn't seem to help.

How can I modify how many methods are omitted by Rubinius' profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -Xprofiler.full_report option.